# How many odd coefficients will there be when expanding $(x^2+x+1)^{33}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How many odd coefficients will there be when expanding $(x^2+x+1)^{33}$

This question seems hard to me because of the $x^2$. I tested it out on wolfram alpha and I got $6$ odd coefficients (coefficients of $x^0 \text{, } x^1 \text{, }x^2 \text{, } x^{64} \text{, } x^{65} \text{, } x^{66}$). I tried to use logic to see the different ways of getting $x^n$ but I am unable to keep track as we can go all the way to $x^{66}$. Is there any simple and algebraic way to prove it. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know about the Frobenius Automorphism, you can work modulo 2 and write $(x^2+x+1)^{33}=(x^2+x+1)^{2^5}×(x^2+x+1)=(x^{2^6}+x^{2^5}+1)(x^2+x+1)$ and from here we see there is enough space between $1$, $2^5$ and $2^6$ so that the answer is $3×3=9$. I think you forgot some coefficients in the middle of the expression around the coefficient of $x^{32}$.

(I initially posted a comment but this is an answer after all.)

Answer (score 2):

We have that
$$[x^n](1+x(1+x))^{33}=[x^n]\sum_{j=0}^{33}\binom{33}{j}x^{33-j}(1+x)^{j}=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{33}{j}\binom{j}{n-j}.$$
Now note that by [Lucas's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) $\binom{33}{j}=\binom{32+1}{j}$ is odd for $j=0,1,32,32+1$ and even otherwise. Hence
$$[x^n](1+x(1+x))^{33}\equiv \binom{0}{n}+\binom{1}{n-1}+
\binom{32}{n-32}+\binom{33}{n-33}\pmod{2}.$$
It is easy to verify that the right-hand side is odd if and only if $n=0,1,2,64,65,66$ (recall that for any non-negative integer $N$, $\binom{N}{K}=0$ when $K<0$ or $K>N$).